# Find a specific string within another string without getting similar results

Tags: c#, regex, search, substring

In a console application I get as input the RTF (Rich text Format) code of a file. The source is a database and data gathered via query.

My goal is to search whether in the input code, as string, is present the code: **\par** (end of carriage in RTF).
I tried with string.IndexOf and string.Contains but both returns me bad results since they match also code like: "\pard".

Given a string like:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}
{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif;}  
\deflang1033\pard\plain\tx0\f2\lang1033\fs20\cf1 Payment}
```

How can I build my condition so that it return false, since the string does **not** contain \par? Eventually how could I set a regex to say that exactly the keyword "\par" (so length 4 chars) and no other will match? Thanks.

EDIT: The language used is C# and I am developing the console application with VS 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't tell us the language you are using, but generally you need a word boundary something like this:

```
\\par\b
```

to ensure that there is not a word character following

Comment: Will this be in the string.Contais("\\par\b")? Or in a Regex?

Comment: No this is regex syntax. In C# you can do e.g. `Regex.IsMatch(text, @"\\par\b")` which returns true when `text` contains the pattern (or false otherwise)